# Is humus useless? What can i do with it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

In newest version on forestry used for ftb unleashed. Whats the point of being able to make humus if nothing uses it anymore? i have tons of humus and nothing i can use it with. x.x

Comment: Short answer, yes, it is useless. Long answer... I mean, it's a block that can be used for building, if you want to build a slightly different dirt house.

Comment: you can use it to convert dirt to sand (when a tree grows on it it converts to sand)

Answer (score 2):

Humus is the block that you use in tree farms that the trees grow on. It does turn to sand after growing a tree on it though and you can't use it for much else.

Answer (score 0):

Humus is just a block that turns into sand after you grow a sapling on it. Other than that, it is very useless. However, if you need some sand for a trap or glass or something along those lines, it can serve that purpose.

Comment: Note that sand is much easier to get by putting cobblestone into a macerator.

Answer (score 0):

Humus is no longer useful by itself since the Multi-Farms have been introduced. It is used when you have your multi-farm configured as a tree farm, but in that case the multi-farm creates the Humus for you and you provide it with fertiliser, water and dirt, rather than directly providing the Humus.